# how i can change AWS ubuntu ec2 shell prompt name

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

When we connect to aws ec2 instance using ubuntu server, after login I see the following prompt at the bash shell

ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx

Is there there a way I can change that text without effect any networking thing in server?

I have searched but didn't find anything that can guide me better in this area. I'd appreciate any help offered.

Comment: The `PS1` variable controls the prompt. See the `bash` manpage.

Comment: Why? What are you accomplishing here?

Answer (score 1):

The key phrase in Google that you want is "how to change ubuntu command prompt", or perhaps "how change bash command prompt". [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt) is the second hit for the first query. I'll copy it in here as per SF preferences

**To change it for the current terminal instance only**
Just enter

```
PS1='\u:\W\$ ' and press enter.
```

**To change it "permanently"**

In your ~/.bashrc, find the following section:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Remove the @\h, and replace the \w with an uppercase \W, so that it becomes:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
fi
```

Comment: i want something like this to show up in my terminal window 

ubuntu@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

You can change the hostname using "hostname" command.

```
$~ hostname yourdomain.com
```

Then login back to your server, the prompt name will be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure this necessarily satisfies the "without effect any networking thing in server" bit.

Comment: i dont want to break netwrok layer, 
what i want to achive is , having multiple putty session with each having its own domain name, each domain name links to its own ec2.

so for examlple ubuntu@domain1.com$
ubuntu@domain2.com$